# Are there signs for Route des Grandes Alpes in Menton, Sospel or anywhere near the end of the route?

Tags: sightseeing, france, road-trips, alps

I want to take a souvenir photo of a Route des Grandes Alpes road sign.  I'll be travelling the route north from Menton.  Where is the nearest sign to Menton showing "Route des Grandes Alpes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is another one nearer to your destination, but at least in [La Grave](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=La%20Grave,%20France&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=81.911385,191.513672&vpsrc=0&t=m&z=13), there is a sign for sure. I pictured it personally last summer.

[Here](http://www.geo-reisecommunity.de/reisebericht/38206/2) I found a German page that has picture the same road sign as I did:

Comment: I found a sign in Sospel; http://g.co/maps/byfj6.

Taking a picture at a Route des Grandes Alpes sign was actually part of a challenge for a fund raising event that I took part in (which went well and raised over £90k).